# deserializing a decimal value in json is always null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

I have problem when sending a decimal value to server,
in fiddler my data is
`{"requestCode":116069}`

my receiver function prototype is

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult SaveBranchSale1(decimal requestCode)
```

but i get a error that means the requestcode can not be null

when i change 
`{"requestCode":116069}` to `{"requestCode":"116069"}`
changing the value to string type the problem will be solved but i have a lot of datamodels that have many decimal datamembers ...

Comment: Maybe, [this][1] help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698984/default-asp-net-mvc-3-model-binder-doesnt-bind-decimal-propeties

Comment: Soooooo thanks, my friend my nightmare went to hell!