# Is this a bug? Decimal property not getting deserialized from JSON string (.NET MVC)

Tags: .net, json, asp.net-mvc-3, deserialization

I have the following .Net class:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public String Name {get;set;}
    public Decimal Price {get;set;}
}
```

And an action in my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddProduct(Product product)
{
       // product.Price is zero!!
}
```

The JSON string posted in the request to `AddProduct` looks like this (grabbed through Fiddler2):

```
POST http://localhost:59656/Cart/AddProduct HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:59656
Origin: http://localhost:59656
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko Chrome/17.0.963.79 Safari/535.11
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Accept: text/html, */*; q=0.01

{"Product":{"ID":1232, "Name":"Blu-Ray","Price":210}}
```

Why is `product.Price` zero while other properties (ID and Name) get hydrated correctly?

Comment: Check the Request.Form collection, look for entry of "Price" and see what the value supplied is.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698984/default-asp-net-mvc-3-model-binder-doesnt-bind-decimal-propeties.

Comment: That collection is empty. The request is not url-encoded, is JSon encoded. I posted HTTP headers too so this is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try posting:
{"Product":{"ID":1232, "Name":"Blu-Ray","Price":210.00}}

I think MVC doesn't cast/convert from int to decimal so the **.00** tells it to hydrate using float/double/decimal.

Comment: Beh.  Stupid Microsoft.  I decided to switch my variables to the long data type, but it's essentially the same fix.  Thanks, Alex!

Comment: @ChrisJaynes see Phil Haacks blog post for a better fix. http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/19/fixing-binding-to-decimals.aspx

Comment: This is not meant to be snarky, but how is writing a big binding function a better fix than just switching the data type to long?  Am I risking some other strange behavior by just using a long?