# MVC: format value in form data at submission

Tags: c#, html, razor

I am sending a value from the form data which has to be received as `decimal?` with comma (`,`) punctuation. Since I am using input `type="number" step="0.1"` the punctuation on the client side is with a dot (`.`).

How can I format the value before the form data is sent to the model?

Comment: Decimals don't have "punctuation" they just have a numeric value. The local culture number formatting might have punctuation but you can't force c# to store decimals with "punctuation", you can/should only format the number into a string (with "punctuation") when you're outputting

Comment: Thank you for clarification. However as long as the 'user' is interacting with the value it is being outputted. I am turning the decimal into a string and replacing "," with "." when outputting. I simply want to revert the punctuation before retrieving it to the model

Comment: Parse it using an appropriate culture you mean? Your question should probably be posed as "I have a string representing a decimal number in {insert name of country or region} so like 1.234,56 and I want to parse it to a decimal".. but this will have been asked before so try s search first?

Comment: @CaiusJard I have realy tried implementing cultureinfo but to no avail. I fixed this problem by creating a ViewModel that carries the information as a string. I then do the punctuation in the controller. 
As I have search a lot regarding this problem I see it less complicated than many other solutions. I just wish there were a single line of code that could fix the problem

Comment: Show the code you've already written?

Comment: @CaiusJard I have the code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57536043/mvc-how-to-fix-null-value-from-httppost-when-formatting-punctuationdecimal-n